# Space between List and top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a design I found on a website and it looks really cool but I wanted to alter it to look like what I need it to be.

The original demo looked like this
 [image]

but I needed them to be side by side, so i created a table that was a width of 100% and two columns. I placed both of the lists in the table but something strange happened.

[image]

I have checked and there isn't a padding on the top nor is there another object there. The list and table are both set to v-align. I have attached a [jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/) for better reference and help.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/)**

Thank you all so much!

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
<tbody valign="top">
<tr valign="top">
  <td valign="top">
  <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tabs__item color1">
        <h2><span>[Review] The New LG G18</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color2">
        <h2><span>[ROM][8.3.1] SlimSaber R31</span> </h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color3">
        <h2><span>[APP] Goo Simulator Extreme</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color4">
        <h2><span>[Tutorial] Pooping Your Pants</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <div class="views-toggle views-toggle--hidden">
        <svg fill="white" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M16.59 8.59l-4.59 4.58-4.59-4.58-1.41 1.41 6 6 6-6z"/>
          <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <script       src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/index.js"></script> 
  </td>
  <td valign="top">
  <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tabs__item color1">
        <h2><span>[Review] The New LG G18</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color2">
        <h2><span>[ROM][8.3.1] SlimSaber R31</span> </h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color3">
        <h2><span>[APP] Goo Simulator Extreme</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <li class="tabs__item color4">
        <h2><span>[Tutorial] Pooping Your Pants</span></h2>
        <p class="tabs__stats">Content</p>
      </li>
      <div class="views-toggle views-toggle--hidden">
        <svg fill="white" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
          <path d="M16.59 8.59l-4.59 4.58-4.59-4.58-1.41 1.41 6 6 6-6z"/>
          <path d="M0 0h24v24h-24z" fill="none"/>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </ul>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/index.js"></script> 
  </td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question. The warning you saw is there for a reason.

Comment: @j08691 I added my HTML. The JAvascript and CSS are on the Fiddle.

Comment: you are loading the code twice  -- can't be good

Comment: Looks like the ones on the right are below the ones on the left. And fiddling around with it, the two stacks are treated as the same stack by the code. Click on a tab, and you can't click on a tab in the other stack until you close the one you just clicked.

Comment: @forgivenson that's the problem. I need then both at the top.

Comment: I looked at your code, and I don't have the exact answer right now, but I'm pretty sure the issue isn't the valign at all. If I'm right, your javascript is automatically generating the positions of each li, and *it looks like* it doesn't know the difference between the two lists. That gives you a top position of 0, 10, 20, 30 in the left column, and then 40, 50, 60, 70 in the right column. Looks like it's the function that starts with `tabs.each(function(index) {` on line 40 in your js

Comment: @BrianD is correct.  You need a class in the tab that tells it to "reset" and then the javascript code to read it.

Comment: Also, re what @Hogan said earlier about loading your code twice: You're loading jquery and your index.js each twice in your html (lines 31/32 and 59/60)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the code you need in the moveTabs function

```
 var indexOffset = 0;       
  tabs.each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('tabs__first'))
       indexOffset = index-1;

    transY  = (index-indexOffset) * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + (index-indexOffset)/25;
```

then add a tabs__first to the class of the first item you want to "reset"

How this works --

- In the loop I check for the tabs___first marker 
    when I see it I set my offset to one less than index
- When doing the transformation on the item instead of using index to do the transformation (as the original code did) I use index-indexOffset.

fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s4sc2mu1/2/

Comment: I guess I wouldn't consider making changes to css or the suggestion to remove the duplicated version of jquery to be wrong, but yes, you are correct that this is a more elegant solution undoubtedly. Good answer!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that the javascript is setting how far down the page the boxes appear based on their index in a list.

```
 transY     = index * 10;
```

I've saved a copy of the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/2/), but here are the changes that need to be made:

Add an id to both of your unordered lists:

```
 <ul class="tabs" id="list1">

 <ul class="tabs" id="list2">
```

In the javascript section, add two more lists, based on the new IDs:

```
var tabs        = $('li.tabs__item');           // current list
var tabs1       = $('#list1 li.tabs__item');    // new list
var tabs2       = $('#list2 li.tabs__item');    // new list
```

Also in the javascript, change this:

```
 tabs.each(function(index) {
    transY  = index * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

    transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
```

to this:

```
 tabs1.each(function(index) {
    transY  = index * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

    transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
  });

 tabs2.each(function(index) {
    transY  = index * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

    transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
```

What we are doing here is getting two seperate lists for the two columns.  We're then running the javascript to set the box positions based on the two seperate lists, so when it uses the index, it will be starting from 0 for each column, instead of continuing in column two where column one left off.

Comment: hmm... this way uses two loops -- mine uses the same loop.  Not sure which is better.

Comment: It is equivalent. Your loop is 8 iterations, his are each 4 iterations.

Comment: I'm going to vote for yours, as it will handle adding more columns of boxes without needing any further changes.  Nice!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this fixes the issue:

```
var Tabs = (function() {

  var toggler = $('.views-toggle');
  var tabs      = $('li.tabs__item');
  var toggled = false;

  var transform = function(el, value) {
    el.css('transform', value);
    el.css('-webkit-transform', value);
    el.css('-ms-transform', value);
  };
   var transition = function(el, value) {
    el.css('transition', value);
    el.css('-webkit-transition', value);
    el.css('-ms-transition', value);
  };

  var moveContent = function() {
    if (!toggled) {
      toggled = true;
    } else {
      toggled = false;
    }

    moveTabs(toggled);

    return false;
  };

  var moveTabs = function(a) {
    var transY, scale;

    if (a) {
      tabs.css({
        'opacity': '1',
        'box-shadow': '0 30px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
        'cursor': 'pointer'
      });

      tabs.each(function(index) {         

        transY  = $(this).index() * 10;        
        scale       = 0.5 + $(this).index()/25;

        transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
      });

      toggler.addClass('views-toggle--hidden');
    } else {
      transform(tabs, 'translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1)');
    }
  };

  var switchTabs = function() {
    var selected = $(this);
    var others = selected.siblings('li');

    if (toggled) {
      transition(others, 'transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06)');
      transform(others, 'translate3d(0, 100%, 0) scale(1)');
      transform(selected, 'translate3d(0,0,0) scale(1)');
      tabs.css({
        'box-shadow': '0 30px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
        'cursor': 'default'
      });
      toggled = false;

      selected.on('transitionend webkitTransitionend', function() {
        toggler.removeClass('views-toggle--hidden');
        others.css({
          'opacity': '0'
        });
        transform(others, 'translate3d(0, 100%, 0) scale(0)');
        transition(others, 'transform 0.9s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
        selected.off('transitionend webkitTransitionend');
      });
    }
  };

  var setup = function() {
    toggled = true;
    moveTabs(toggled);
  };

  var init = function() {
    $(document).on('ready', setup);
        toggler.on('click touchstart', moveContent);
    tabs.on('click touchstart', switchTabs);
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

}());

Tabs.init();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/5/

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript

```
  tabs.each(function(index) {
    transY  = index * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

    transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
```

is never being reset, so you are transforming that second column as if they were being added to the first column.

You need better logic for setting "transY". Currently you are setting it based on the index of the list of "tab"s, so tab 1 is 10vh's down, tab 2 is 20vh's down and tab 7 is 70vh's down.

## A simple easy to understand solution

If you know there will always be 4 "tabs" per column you could do a hard coded fix by modifying the above to:

```
  tabs.each(function(index) {
    transY  = (index%4) * 10;        
    scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

    transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
  });
```

Otherwise you will need to rework the logic behind setting "tabs" y location to not be based solely on the number of "tabs". This is only here for educational purposes to show you why your logic was wrong and a simple solution that doesn't use complex techniques.

EDIT:

## Solution using Jquery tree navigation

A none hard coded solution that is a bit more complex. The logic is to grab every "tabs" list and for each child in that "tabs" list grab each list element with class "tabs__item" and transform their height based on that. This is 100% modular and will work for any number of "tab__item"s within any number of "tabs" for any number of "tabs" and does not require any modification of CSS files or changes to your current structure.

```
  $('.tabs').each(function(index) {
      $(this).children('li.tabs__item').each(function(index) {
          transY    = index * 10;        
          scale     = 0.5 + index/25;

          transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
      });
   });
```

JS Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/8/

Answer (score -1):

check this out now:
https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/3/

The thing is, every window is being set with parameters through index.
But the script counts ALL windows, not only in the particular cell.
This is not a real solution, but at least this shows where you need to think futher, here what I've updated:

```
 tabs.each(function(index) {
          if (index % 4 == 1){
          index=1;
          }
          if (index % 4 == 2){
          index=2;
          } 
          if (index % 4 == 3){
          index=3;
          }          
          if (index % 4 == 0){
          index=0;
          }
        transY  = index * 10;        
        scale       = 0.5 + index/25;

        transform($(this), 'translate3d(0,' + transY + 'vh, 0) scale(' + scale + ')');
      });
```

Comment: This is horrible -- if he has more than 4 items it won't work.

Comment: hey man, you wrote: "I have checked and there isn't a padding on the top nor is there another object there" so you were thinking about "where the bug is". For testing purposes I played with index - and showed you WHERE the problem lays. But you want me to do the whole thing for you, don't you?

Comment: hey, Hogan, what would you say if one does something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/trn44k7j/5/